# Java - returning JSON from servlet with Gson library

Tags: java, json, servlets, return, gson

I am using GSON library.
I have a programm which returns JSON.
JSON constructs and returns in this way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//findNewComments returns List<Comment> comments
return gson.toJson(service.findNewComments(id,lastId));
```

So the result is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 43,
        "entryId": 19,
        "author": " m8w46",
        "body": "mw86",
        "date": "WED 9, 2011"
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "entryId": 19,
        "author": " n7w4",
        "body": "nw77w4",
        "date": "WED 9, 2011"
    }
]
```

But this array must be named as "comments"!

```
"comments": [
    {
        "id": 43,
        "entryId": 19,
        "author": " m8w46",
        "body": "mw86",
        "date": "WED 9, 2011"
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "entryId": 19,
        "author": " n7w4",
        "body": "nw77w4",
        "date": "WED 9, 2011"
    }
]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: can it be an object with one element, {"comments":[...]} ?

Comment: return "\"comments\":" + gson.toJson(service.findNewComments(id,lastId)); ???

Comment: Why does it have to have such a wrapper? That adds no real information in there, why not just return JSON array as is?

Comment: I only do it if the client code expects a particular format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is acceptable to you but:

```
public class CommentWrapper {
    List<Comments> comments;
    public CommentWrapper(List<Comment> comments) {
       this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
return new Gson().toJson(new CommentWrapper(service.findNewComments(id,lastId)));
```

Which results in:

```
{
    "comments": [
        ....your data here...
    ]
}
```

Not sure if the object syntax is acceptable to you or not.

Comment: Ye, thank you. I thought that there is some easier way, but it seems that it is the only one.

Comment: I usually make the wrapper class an inner class of whatever controller/servlet I'm working in, because typically it has no use outside that.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I am trying to show elements of this array with javascript, but it says, that they are undefined, but the cycle works fine!. What am I doing: var json = eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");  for(var comment in json.comments){alert(comment.author);}

Comment: @Lomer: I'm not a javascript expert you're probably better served by posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from wrapper object, you can also use a simple `java.util.Map` with single entry, possibly bit less code.